# Arguments mismatch using where IN clause in query

Tags: sql, linux, bash, hive

I have column in `hive` table like below

```
testing_time
2018-12-31 14:45:55
2018-12-31 15:50:58
```

Now I want to get the `distinct` values as a variable so I can use in another query.

I have done like below

```
abc=`hive -e "select collect_set(testing_time)) from db.tbl";`

echo $abc

["2018-12-31 14:45:55","2018-12-31 15:50:58"]

xyz=${abc:1:-1}
```

when I do

```
hive -e "select * from db.tbl where testing_time in ($xyz)"
```

I get below error

```
Arguments for IN should be the same type! Types are {timestamp IN (string, string)
```

what the the mistake I am doing?

What is the correct way of achieving my result?

> > Note: I know I can use subquery for this scenario but I would like to use variable to achieve my result

Comment: the problem is with datatype and argument mismatch and error message suggests.  `xyz is string and testing_time is timestamp`

Comment: @GaurangShah I get that point but when I use `collect_set` I am getting the values as string. How can I make it a timestamp

Comment: it's not the issue with `collect_set`, Shell doesn't have `timestamp` data type so when you are string in variable that's when it gets stored as string.

Comment: @GaurangShah How can I correct it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem is that you're comparing *timestamp* (column `testing_time`) with *string* (i.e. `"2018-12-31 14:45:55"`), so you need to convert string to timestamp, which you can do via `TIMESTAMP(string)`.

Here's a bash script that adds the conversion:

```
RES=""                             #  here we will save the resulting SQL
IFS=","
read -ra ITEMS <<< "$xyz"          # split timestamps into array
for ITEM in "${ITEMS[@]}"; do
    RES="${RES}TIMESTAMP($ITEM),"  # add the timestamp to RES variable,
                                   # surrounded by TIMESTAMP(x)
done
unset IFS
RES="${RES%?}"                     # delete the extra comma
```

Then you can run the constructed SQL query:

```
hive -e "select * from db.tbl where testing_time in ($RES)"
```